# How to create a 3D barplot with fitted curve in R

Tags: r, bar-chart, surface

I'm trying to make a figure similar to [this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Almaz-Torgoev/post/How-the-value-of-curvature-returned-by-ArcGIS-is-affected-by-the-resolution-of-input-DEM/attachment/59d624916cda7b8083a2001f/AS%3A393817976000545%401470904932118/image/Curvature.jpg) in R. Basically X and Y represent coordinates (e.g. lon/lat) and Z represents elevation. I want to plot a 3D bar chart with a elevation as the bar height, and then show a smooth curve of fitted Z values going through the bars. I am able to get a 3d barplot with barplot3d but I'm not sure if it's possible to add the fitted curve on top of that. Does anyone know how to do this? I have some example code below demonstrating what I've tried so far.

```
library(rgl)
library(barplot3d)
library(tidyverse)

x_mat<- matrix(rep(-1:1, each=3),nrow = 3) #x coordinates
y_mat<- matrix(rev(rep(-1:1, each=3)),nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE) #y coordinates

df<- data.frame(x = as.vector(x_mat), y = as.vector(y_mat)) #dataframe
set.seed(5)
df<- df %>% mutate(z= x^2+ y^2 + rnorm(n = 9, mean = 0, sd = 0.1)) #add elevation values

m<- lm(z ~ I(x^2)+I(y^2)+I(x*y)+x+y, data = df) #fitted curve

rgl.open()
rgl::plot3d(m)
barplot3d(rows=3,cols=3, z=df$z,scalexy=1, gap=0, alpha=0.4,theta=30,phi=50,
          topcolors = "gray", gridlines = TRUE)
```

[image]

## Update: More complicated example

The curve doesn't seem to intersect the bars properly with current solution for a non-symmetrical curve (fixed in most updated answer).

```
library(rgl)
library(barplot3d)
library(tidyverse)

x_mat<- matrix(rep(-1:1, each=3),nrow = 3) #x coordinates
y_mat<- matrix(rev(rep(-1:1, each=3)),nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE) #y coordinates
A<- 0.2
B<- 0.2
C<- 0.4
D<- 0.4
E<- 0

df<- data.frame(x = as.vector(x_mat), y = as.vector(y_mat)) #dataframe
df<- df %>% mutate(z= A*x^2 + B*y^2 + C*x*y + D*x + E*y) #add elevation values
z_mat<- matrix(data = df$z, nrow=3)

m<- lm(z ~ I(x^2)+I(y^2)+I(x*y)+x+y, data = df) #fitted curve
df$zpred<- predict(m, data.frame(x=df$x, y=df$y))
round(df$z-df$zpred,10) #Predictions should fit observations almost exactly (i.e. intersect exactly with bars)
#0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

n<- 10
xvals <- seq(-1, 1, len = n)
xmat <- replicate(n, seq(1.5, 3.5, len = n))
ymat <- t(xmat)
pred <- expand.grid(x = xvals, y = xvals)
zmat <- matrix(predict(m, pred), nrow = n, ncol = n)

barplot3d(rows=3,cols=3, z=df$z, gap=0, alpha=0.4, phi = 45,
          topcolors = "gray", sidecolors = "cyan", linecolors= "blue", gridlines = FALSE, zlabels = FALSE)
surface3d(x = xmat, y = zmat,  z = ymat-5, color = "purple", alpha = 0.7)
axes3d()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can probably tell, your 3d surface is rotated 90 degrees relative to where it should be. This is not your fault; it is just a difference between the way `barplot3d` is drawn compared to the other `rgl` shapes. You also need a bit of shifting and rescaling to get it to fit.

```r
barplot3d(rows=3,cols=3, z=df$z, gap=0, alpha=0.4, phi = 45,
          topcolors = "gray", gridlines = TRUE)

xvals <- seq(-1.5, 1.5, len = 10)
xmat <- replicate(10, seq(1, 4, len = 10))
ymat <- t(xmat)
pred <- expand.grid(x = xvals, y = xvals)
zmat <- matrix(predict(m, pred), 10, 10)

surface3d(xmat, zmat, color = "gold", alpha = 0.5, ymat - 5)
```

[image]

---

**Update**

To remove the points above the highest bar, just set them to `NA`. You probably want to increase the resolution when you do this though:

```r
xvals <- seq(-1.5, 1.5, len = 100)
xmat <- replicate(100, seq(1, 4, len = 100))
ymat <- t(xmat) - 5

pred <- expand.grid(x = xvals, y = xvals)
zmat <- matrix(predict(m, pred), 100, 100)

zmat[zmat > 2] <- NA

barplot3d(rows=3,cols=3, z=df$z, gap=0, alpha=0.4, phi = 45,
          topcolors = "gray", gridlines = TRUE)

surface3d(xmat, zmat, color = "gold", alpha = 0.5, ymat)
```

[image]

Note that this gives an unavoidably ragged edge to the graphic

An alternative is to shrink the x, y grids at which z is calculated:

```r
xvals <- seq(-1, 1, len = 100)
xmat <- replicate(100, seq(1.5, 3.5, len = 100))
ymat <- t(xmat) - 5

pred <- expand.grid(x = xvals, y = xvals)
zmat <- matrix(predict(m, pred), 100, 100)

barplot3d(rows=3,cols=3, z=df$z, gap=0, alpha=0.4, phi = 45,
          topcolors = "gray", gridlines = TRUE)

surface3d(xmat, zmat, ymat, color = "gray20", alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

---

**Further update**

It looks as though we need a double flip to get the z values correct:

```r
barplot3d(rows=3,cols=3, z=df$z, gap=0, alpha=0.4, phi = 45,
          topcolors = "gray", sidecolors = "cyan", linecolors= "blue", 
          gridlines = FALSE, zlabels = FALSE)
surface3d(x = xmat, y = t(apply(t(apply(zmat, 1, rev)), 2, rev)),  
          z = ymat-5, color = "purple", alpha = 0.7)
axes3d()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Allan! Is there a way to trim the limits of the surface so that it just goes until the predicted value at the center of the outermost bars so that I don't get those high corners? I tried just changing xvals to go from -1 to 1 instead of -1.5 to 1.5 but that seems to offset the predictions (i.e. the predictions no longer intersect the center of the bar).

Comment: @ailich see my update. Unfortunately, you will get a ragged edge to your surface if you do this

Comment: Hey Allan, I'm running into issues expanding this to non symmetrical curves (see updated question). It seems almost as if the curve needs to be reflected (peak of curve is in the front right but needs to be in the back left).

Comment: @ailich see my update. It seems we need a double flip / transpose to get the correct z values.